# Why is android unable of finding my file?

Tags: java, android, file, filenotfoundexception

I want to access a file in included in the folder of the app and I want to be able to access it localy. I also don't want to use methods like android.getresources() and just use
`File file = new File( filePath );`
My file is saved in app/src/main/assets/ball.obj

The problem is when I do `File file = new File("app/src/main/assets/ball.obj");`, it alwas gives me a FileNotFoundException. I also tried moving the file in other places and absolute pathes, but it still doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My file is saved in app/src/main/assets/ball.obj

That is a relative path to a file on your development machine. **Assets are not files on the filesystem of the device**. You cannot use `File` to access an asset.

To get an `InputStream` on your asset, [call `getAssets()` on your `Activity` or other `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets()), then [call `open()` on the `AssetManager` returned by `getAssets()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager#open(java.lang.String)).

For your call to `open()`, you need to pass in the relative path within `assets/` to the asset that you wish to read in. So, if you are in a method of your `Activity`, `getAssets().open("ball.obj")` will give you an `InputStream` that you can use to read in the contents of that particular asset.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I am calling it in a class that is run by my Activity. Do you think passing it down will work? Also, I want to read the file like a txt file, does that chage anything?

Comment: @Gyoo: "Do you think passing it down will work?" -- if you mean passing the `Activity` as a parameter to some method, then yes. "Also, I want to read the file like a txt file, does that chage anything?" -- not really.